# Flash Slide Presentation full screen

Tags: flash, fullscreen

I am building my very first Flash Slide Presentation.

However, I would like to enable full screen when the presentation starts.
I placed:

```
fscommand("fullscreen", "true");
```

In the first layer, first frame, of the first slide.
And I use a .html file to launch to embed the .swf file.

However, when I open the .html, a popup appears saying:
“Adobe Flash Player has stopped a potentially unsafe operation.”

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash has all kinds of permissions for everything.  The first thing to check, since this is embedded in an html page, is that the object tag allows full screen.

```
<object ...>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<embed ... allowFullScreen="true" ... />
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure, I believe that flash is stopping it because it's something a malicious flash virus might do. I've never personally heard of a malicious flash virus, but I know that if you try to click on a link in a local flash file version 6 and older, it'll do roughly the same thing and have a link to adobe's site to change flash's settings.

As to how to actually fix it I'm not sure as I don't know exactly why it's caused. It may just be because it's running on a local computer.